# How to use a Mac ssh key in Putty (Windows)?

Tags: windows, macos, ssh, terminal, putty

I have generated a ssh key in the terminal of my Mac. How can I use this private key in Putty on my Windows pc? I don't want to generate a new ssh key for each computer.

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to generate one for each computer? Security wise, that's the "right" thing to do.

Comment: I have over 20 pc's...

Comment: Still, it's probably faster to generate them than copy them (with reservation for not having generated one with putty)

Comment: Is there no way to create a private keyfile (e.g. .ppk )?

Comment: [This](http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html) should hopefully help.

Comment: Please add your comment as answer. So I can give you the points and close this question. This links solved my problem! :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To convert an `id_rsa` file to an `id_rsa.ppk`, you can use puttygen from [putty's web site](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

- Choose **File->Load Private Key**
- Enter the private key password if applicable
- Press the button **Save private key**.

The converted key would be saved as "id_rsa.ppk".